# How to write footer using iTextSharp 5.0.4

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to write a footer using ITextSharp library 5.0.4 and not able to print page number since OnEndPage and OnClosePage are not getting called.

This is a simple console app where I am printing tables to generate couple of pages and expecting OnEndPage or OnClosePage to get called where my code for footer will get executed once document.close() method gets executed.

Please let me know what must be wrong with this ?

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Answer (score 3):

well i found how to create footer with page number and image with no complications. i-m using itextsharp 5.1.2. it's pretty easy.
Step 1: create a .cs document in APP_Code with the name... in my case "pdfPage.cs" 
Step 2: Copy and Paste this code inside :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;


namespace myApp.ns.pages

{
   public class pdfPage : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
   {

       public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
       {

           BaseColor grey = new BaseColor(128, 128, 128);
           Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.NORMAL, grey);
           //tbl footer
            PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            footerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;
           //img footer
            iTextSharp.text.Image foot= iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("footer.jpg"));
            foot.ScalePercent(45);

            footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(foot);
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER ;
            cell.Border = 0;
            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);


            //page number
            Chunk myFooter = new Chunk("Page " +  (doc.PageNumber), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8, grey));
            PdfPCell footer = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myFooter));    
            footer.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;    
            footer.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; 
            footerTbl.AddCell(footer); 

         //this is for the position of the footer ... im my case is "+80"
         footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0,-1, 0, (doc.BottomMargin + 80),  writer.DirectContent);
       }

    }

}
```

and save it.

Last step: write in the .cs file that creates the pdf " using myApp.ns.pages; " at the begining.

That's all

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a class that extends `PdfPageEventHelper` and override OnStartPage and `OnEndPage` there.  Use this helper class to handle the `PageEvent` in your `PdfWriter`.

Massoud Mazar's blog post [Code sample for using iTextSharp PDF library](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx) has a fine example.

If you're doing this and still have problems please post some code.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I had already refered that blog , only thing remaining was to assign writer.pageevents

Comment: writer.PageEvent = PageEventHandler;